# Format date - Lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I'm displaying a date field on the Aura component. Following is the code,

```
<aura:iteration items= "!v.contactList}" var="type">
<lightning:tile label="{!type.Name}">
        End Date:
        <li class="slds-item">{!type.EndDate__c}</li>
    </lightning:tile>
</aura:iteration>
```

I'm getting the output as, Output Date : 2020-04-02

I want the output to be in `MM/DD/YYYY` format.

How can I get format that on Lightning side.

Answer (score 2):

Use the date formatter:

```
<li class="slds-item"><lightning:formattedDateTime value="{!type.EndDate__c}"/></li>
```

This component has a number of attributes to control how the date is formatted. Refer to the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:formattedDateTime/example#lightningcomponentdemo:exampleDateFormatting) for details.